# cd command to navigate to external hard disk which is already mounted

Tags: command-line, hard-drive

I m new to ubundu and need help.
I plugged an external USB hard drive into my laptop and its icon is shown on desktop with name 'New Volume'. how to navigate into this drive using cd in linux. I tried `cd New Volume` and got error as `bash: cd: too many arguments` .
I tried `df -hk` and found my disk as `dev/sdb5       1.9T  1.9T  2.7G 100% /media/alok/New Volume`
I also tried `cd media/alok/New Volume`and got the same error `bash: cd: too many arguments`
kindly provide the command to navigate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the name of the directory you are trying to navigate to has a space in it, you must put quotes around it. If you don't, cd doesn't know if the space is part of the path or a new argument.

this command should work: `cd "/media/alok/New Volume"`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and help